# Stability of a fixed point of planar system

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Study the stability of the fixed point $(0,0)$ of the following planar linear difference system: $$x_{k+1}=\frac{3}{5}x_k+\frac{1}{5}y_k, \ y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{5}x_k+\frac{3}{5}y_k $$

Can somebody give me some ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

Study the eigenvalues of the system $X_{n+1} = AX_n$, where 
$X_n = \begin{bmatrix}
       x_n \\
       y_n \\
       \end{bmatrix} $
and $A  = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{3}{5} & \frac{1}{5} \\
    \frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{5} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Thank you! I got it now